# Custom permissions for route created within Views

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-views

I have a custom view that creates a tab on a node page.  I have several content types, but I only want the tab to show on some of them.  If this were a regular route, I'd just throw a custom_access under requirements, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that with routes created outside a routing.yml file.

Is there a reasonable way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create custom route subscriber. File custom_module.services.yml:

```
services:
  custom_module.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\custom_module\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

File RouteSubscriber.php:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\custom_module\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if($route = $collection->get('view.<view_name>.<view_bundle>')){ // Need to change view_name and view_bundle.
      $route->setRequirement(
        '_custom_access',
        '\Drupal\custom_module\Routing\RouteSubscriber::viewsAccess'
      );
    }
  }

  public function viewsAccess() {
    return AccessResult::allowedIf(
      // Add condition when view has access
    );
  }
}
```